# Attach debugger to app pool on recycle

Tags: debugging, exception, iis, windbg, w3wp.exe

I need to debug a dll that's getting loaded on a specific application pool process. I'm using WinDbg, and so far I have successfully found the correct w3wp.exe process. Problem is, the app pool recycles itself, sometimes before it reaches what I want to find (a very elusive second chance exception). Then, I need to start over.
How do I configure WinDbg to automatically attach to a w3wp.exe process that's connected to a specific app pool, every time it starts?
Another solution would be to get the crash dump - I tried using ADPlus.exe for this but it also needs to be started on a process and I didn't find a way to re-run it automatically on only the process I need AND every time it starts.

So to sum it up, I need a way to get a crash dump from a w3wp.exe process that's connected to a specific IIS App Pool when it crashes on a second chance exception, while the process gets restarted once in a while (not enough time for me to run the debug tools manually each time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I discovered this awesome tool called DebugDiag, which is  an official Microsoft tool. It has a nice interface that allows collecting dumps on certain events, such as exceptions, and creates very useful logs.
On top of that - it has a special section specifically for IIS debugging, which allowed me to select the app pool I was interested in.
Download available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924).